# How to change widget's icons in the service-links module?

Tags: 7

I am using the [Service links](https://drupal.org/project/service_links) module in Drupal 7.

I tried to change the icons of the links, but only the "general services" links are changed. The "widget services" staying like the original. I saw that is because the icon is coming from an URL and not from a picture on the computer.

How can I change the widget icon?

Is there a patch or an option on the module?

Answer (score 1):

CSS solution for position:
for services widgets (FB, pinterest, linkedin) you can not change images, for General Services (twitter, G+) you can upload your own images.

Here is my CSS code and links appear centered inline.

```
/* services share links */`
.service-links ul li {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline;
 overflow: hidden;
 list-style: none;
 padding-right: 10px;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 float: left;
 }

.service-links li {
 display:inline;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 position: relative;
 }
.service-links .service-links-linkedin-share-button {
top: 5px;
}

.service-links .service-links-facebook-share {
bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way would be if the module allowed us to insert our own images to the site, but this was requested previously and Closed (won't fix) https://www.drupal.org/node/1895012#comment-10310687

I did however managed to find a workaround for this by inserting my own custom images using CSS, and adding the new images to my theme. I +1 this as a feature request, as hiding the existing images with 'display:none' is certainly not ideal.

You can see a live example of this code in action at http://www.kindconsumer.com in the 'Share' section at the bottom.

`.service-links a {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.service-links img {
  display: none;
}

.service-links-facebook {
  background: url(../img/facebook.png) 0 0 no-repeat transparent;
}

.service-links-linkedin {
  background: url(../img/linkedin.png) 0 0 no-repeat transparent;
}

.service-links-twitter {
  background: url(../img/twitter.png) 0 0 no-repeat transparent;
}`